# Silently detecting whether a camera is installed

Tags: javascript, html, video-capture, getusermedia

With  `navigator.getUserMedia` I can request a camera stream. If no camera is installed the errorCallback will be invoked. But if there is a camera the user will be prompted with a security request.

Is it possible to "silently" detect whether a camera is installed, so that I can build different UIs on this detection, without bothering the user with a getUserMedia request?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could, I would hate to be filmed without my knowledge x)

Comment: This is not the question. I don't want to access the camera stream without a request. I want to know whether there is at least one camera. I don't need to build a UI, which gives the user a button "take picture" if I already know, that the user has no camera.

Comment: Well, the user can technically plug an USB camera or enable the camera hardware (think laptop with fn key) after seeing your "take picture" UI. In those cases the detection would fail.

Comment: @alexabderfarkas I understand, although that would mean the Browser would have some kind of access to system hardware regardless of permission?

Comment: @MackieeE: So your point is that even admitting the existence of certain hardware should be refused, without explicit user-permission?

Comment: @MackieeE Yes, but the browser has access to it before the user explicitly gives permission to use it. In action script you have an API to get a list of cameras and it also detects changes, in case the user adds or removes one. So 1. it is possible to add it, 2. it's not a security/privacy issue and 3. it makes sense to know it, because you want be able to implement different UI and/or text informations for the user, depending on this detection.

Comment: @alex, ActionScript is not the browser, it's the Flash plugin. Two different beasts, with different security requirements.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas that makes sense. I don't think JS has an equivalent though. It is technically possible to communicate AS with JS, but you will need to write a small flash file and of course, the user's browser must support the flash runtime then.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi In case you have already used getUserMedia you would have seen, that the browser has this information, before the user gives his permission. Actionscript was only an example. That there is an API.

Comment: @alex, the browser *may* have the information before the call (though I wonder how you're so sure about that), but for security reasons it doesn't want to share it with you without the user's permission. In the current state of the media APIs, merely *asking* for a camera's presence is already asking too much. Need to know, etc.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes exactly, this is what I already have done. But in case the user has no flash but native getUserMedia I have a problem.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas +1 to the question, will be interesting to see some answers or workarounds. Apologies Alex for starting a very trivial comment; (Although Oddthinking personally, *yes*).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You don't seem to know the getUserMedia API. If I invoke it and the user has no camera installed, i will get immediately a notsupported error (without asking the user). If there is one installed the browsers allows the user to switch between all installed cameras (This is a brwoser control, not a system control) and then i get either a success stream or a permission denied error. So all informations are provided to a developer already. Having this API only gives me the possibility to alter my UI before I use the API. But if I want, I already have access to the information.

Comment: @alex, ah, I see your point. Yes, the browser does not need to ask the user when no camera is installed because there is no possible security issue in this case. However, if there was an API that returned the presence of a camera, that API would most probably have to ask the user before returning `true` (but not `false)`, as an attacker *knowing* a usable camera is present is already a potential issue. Anyway, to my knowledge such an API does not exist (yet).